# Not Redirected to custom 404 page

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I created my custom 404 error page. I run it on my local, then, it redirects me to custom 404 error page while I run it on my server, it is not redirecting to custom 404 error page.

for example:
`mywebsitename.com/newfile`

here, `newfile` doesn't exist. It gives an error code 404 but it is not redetecting to custom 404 error page.

It shows this message
[image]

This is my .htaccess code

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404error.php
ErrorDocument 100 /404error.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ adduser.php?user=$1
```

Can somebody help me what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: What URL are you requesting? "I also tried with this line" - But that line has nothing to do with this?! "it redirected to my custom 404 page" - that line would not do that?? "It shows this message" - What is generating that response? That is not a standard Apache error response.

Comment: @MrWhite I updated the error image. Response code is 404 but still not redirecting to custom 404 page.

Comment: Does your `.htaccess` file work at all?  Are your rewrite rules having the desired effect?  If not, you may just not have `.htaccess` files turned on in your server config.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller My all links are working fine except custom 404 error page in .htaccess

Comment: Is there anything in your error log about your `ErrorDocument`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller there is nothing in error logs. maybe i'm missing something here.

Comment: As per my first comment... "What is generating that response?" - Examine the HTTP response headers for this `/newfile` request and add them to your question. (ie. in the "Network" tab of devtools, click on the "newfile" request line - in your screenshot - to see the HTTP request/response headers.) Specifically, check the `Server` HTTP response header. To confirm, requests of the form `/user/something` are correctly rewritten to `adduser.php`? (Although that does seem rather "dangerous" if that literally does "add a user"?! The regex is also far too general.)